# Maps link snapping back to user location

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have been sitting on this problem for a while: in my app I use an link that opens the Apple Maps app at specific coordinates. The problem however is that when my app and the maps app are opened for the first time the map snaps back to the location of the user. I have read a dozen of questions covering this topic but they all use mapKit instead of an shared application so that didn't help me a lot.

I use the `UIApplication` object to open the app. My complete code:

```
UIApplication *maps = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    float latitude = 52.379189;
    float longitude = 4.899431;
    NSURL *mapsURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.apple.com/?sll=%f,%f&z=10", latitude, longitude]];
    if ([maps canOpenURL:mapsURL]) {
        [maps openURL:mapsURL options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Can't open the maps app");
    }
```

For more info on the map link conventions check [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html) out

Any idea's on how to approach this problem? Should I drop this method and use mapKit instead? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have the same problem in an app, but I never figured out what the reason for it was. I never made the connection that it only happens when the maps app is opened for the first time. I guess it is simply a bug on Apple's side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! I used the build in MapKit class. I now use this code:

```
float latitude = 52.379189;
float longitude = 4.899431;

MKPlacemark *location = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)];
MKMapItem *maps = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:location];
[maps setName:@"Site x"];
[maps openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:nil];
```

An additional benefit is that you can specify the name of the location and in the maps app you can easily make an route to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with this url format please, may be the ll parameter is missing:

```
let theApp = UIApplication.shared
let latitude = 52.379189
let longitude = 4.899431
let urlString = String(format: "http://maps.apple.com/?sll=%f,%f&ll=%f,%f&z=10", latitude, longitude, latitude, longitude)
let url = URL(string: urlString)!

if theApp.canOpenURL(url)
{
    theApp.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
} else
{
    print("Can't open the maps app")
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that also does not work. It still snaps back the first time